# Questions relating to a novel asset pricing model

Tags: bonds, assets

I'm creating a pricing model for an asset that is similar to a bond, but there are some quirks that I'm unsure how to work out. The asset is a tax lien, in which delinquent tax bills (usually on property taxes) are sold at auction to private investors, who then pay the subsequent tax bills on the property, charging interest to the tax payer, until the tax payer "redeems" their tax lien by paying the delinquent bills pluss that interest to the tax buyer.

Let's say Jane's tax lien made up of $3000 in delinquent taxes is sold to Harry for that amount. When the next tax bill of $1500 comes due and Jane still hasn't redeemed her tax lien, then Harry will pay that tax bill for Jane, and then charge her 12% interest on that $1500. This continues until Jane redeems her tax bill including all the subsequent payments and all the interest due on them (or until Harry forecloses upon Jane's house because she hasn't paid for long enough).

In this way, a tax lien should be similar to a bond in terms of modelling, but with negative cashflows until the point of maturity. My question relates to what I should use for the discount rate. The auctions for these tax liens typically work in such a way that price data isn't really accurate (they have artificial price ceilings which are reached in a majority of cases), so I'm unsure if calculating yield through price data is the correct approach. Should I perhaps use yields from US treasury bonds for my discount rate?

Comment: FWIW, this sounds like a good way to go broke fast. If folks aren't paying taxes, they aren't going to repay you either.

Comment: Usually tax foreclosure auctions include the rights to the property, not just the debt (or not at all the debt). This business model makes no sense.

Comment: @littleadv Actually, a majority of US states hold auctions for tax liens, and many of these sales function in the manner that I described. Look, for instance, to the system in Florida: https://dewittlaw.com/foreclosure/6041/how-do-tax-deed-sales-in-florida-work-what-liens-survive/#:~:text=According%20to%20Florida%20law%2C%20the%20Tax%20Collector%20must,to%20force%20a%20public%20auction%20of%20the%20property.

Comment: @Felix_Farb wouldn't take Florida for an example of reasonable behavior :-D But even there, there's a foreclosure process and not just a debt: "*If the Tax Lien Certificate has not been paid off within two years from the date the taxes became delinquent, the holder of the certificate can apply to force a public auction of the property*".

Comment: @littleadv Yes, but the foreclosure occurs only if the taxpayer fails to repay the tax buyer. The tax buyer is paying for a lien on the property taxes, not the property itself. Foreclosure actually happens only in a small minority of cases. Most of the time, a tax lien is similar to a bond with negative cashflows and an uncertain date of repayment (because the tax payer is allowed to pay at any time).

Comment: @Felix_Farb not sure we are speaking the same language here. The foreclosure is an inherent part of the product here. No one would buy these certificates if they were just debt instruments